# Replacing space after number with hard space in p tag

Tags: php, html, replace, non-breaking-characters

I would like to replace a space after a number with hard-space " " only in p tags.

I wrote this code:

```
   $pattern = "/<p>[0-9] <\/p>/";
   return preg_replace($pattern, "$1&nbsp;", $text);
```

But it does nothing, why? Can you please help?

Example:

```
Input : "My 90 days work."
Output: "My 90&nbsp;days work."
```

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```php
$text = '<p>My 90 days 123 work.</p>';
$pattern = "/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/";
$text = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) {
    $content = $matches[1];
    $content = preg_replace('/(\d+)\s/', '$1&nbsp;', $content);
    return "<p>{$content}</p>";
}, $text);
```

Comment: Hi, thx, it´s working but only for the first 2 numbers in the p tag. Could you please change, that it works for every number? thx

Comment: @JosefKuchař I've updated the code so it should work with more than 1 number sets

Comment: @JosefKuchař Awesome, if you could mark my post as the answer that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Matching html with a regex is not advisable, but if there can be no angle brackets in between, you might get away with a single pattern using the `\G` anchor:

```
(?:<p>(?=[^<>]*</p>)|\G(?!^))[^\d<>]*\d+\K\h
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `<p>(?=[^<>]*</p>)` Match `<p>` and assert a closing `</p>` without angle brackets in between
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match, but not at the start of the string
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `[^\d<>]*` Match optional chars other than `<` or `>` or a digit
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `\h` Match a single horizontal whitespace char

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ny2ut3/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/aTntK).

```
$re = '~(?:<p>(?=[^<>]*</p>)|\G(?!^))[^\d<>]*\d+\K\h~';
$str = '<p>My 90 days 123 work.</p>';

echo preg_replace($re, "&nbsp", $str);
```

**Output**

```
<p>My 90&nbspdays 123&nbspwork.</p>
```

---

Or using [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to find the paragraphs, and do the replacement after matching a digit and a horizontal whitespace char:

```
$str = '<p>My 90 days 123 work.</p>';
$domDoc = new DOMDocument;
$domDoc->loadHTML($str, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
foreach ($domDoc->getElementsByTagName('p') as $p) {
    echo preg_replace("/\d\K\h/", "&nbsp", $p->nodeValue);
}
```

**Output**

```
My 90&nbspdays 123&nbspwork.
```